# App storage allocation and low storage notification

Tags: ios, optimization, notifications, storage, limit

I'm working on a project that stores many images when the app is running.

Say for instance an app when installed uses about 30 megabytes of device storage, but after it launches and during operating, it requires 90 megabytes additional storage to operate properly.

Does iOS allocate and limit storage for apps when they run?

Does iOS notify apps when storage is low or completely used, and if so in what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Does iOS allocate and limit storage for apps when they run?`

iOS does not limit storage. If a device runs out of it, you'll get write fails.

`Does iOS notify apps when storage is low or completely used, and if so in what way?`

There is no such notification to subscribe for. I suggest you just to check the free space left periodically and swiftly handle write errors.

As for you case you could allocate some kind of a scratch file for "reserving" the capacity you need, but this is not a friendly approach.

You could also notify the user that x MBs of space is left and app will stop working if it's gone under y MBs of space.